# Python: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, bash, pycharm, popen

I have added the path to mytool in .bashrc and I could run `mytool --help` from any path in bash shell. However when when I run the following snippet, I get :

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in
>   _execute_child
>       raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

```
import subprocess

command_array = ['mytool', '--help']

p = subprocess.Popen(command_array,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    )

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line)
p.stdout.close()
```

How can I resolve this?

EDIT: When I run the python file from terminal (bash), it works fine. But when I run from PyCharm (debugger) or other shells it is giving the above error.

How do I change my script so that it runs 'mytool' in bash when I run the script from other shells? I need the environment added in .bashrc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this print to your file:

```
import os
print os.environ['PATH']
```

Compare the outputs after running the script from IDE and terminal.
You should observe that the IDE's `PATH` does not include the `mytool`'s directory.

Comment: The path that is printed doesn't have the paths added to .bashrc. How do I change my script so that it runs 'mytool' in bash when I run the script from other shells?

Comment: Try one of two (or both): 1) `command_array = ['/path/to/mytool', '--help']` 2) Update the `PATH` environment variable in your IDE ([howTo](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html))

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

`Run/Debug Configurations` -> `Environment variables`

Add fallowing:

`PATH` = to output to you shell `echo $PATH`